# Android app title bar sticks in recent apps view

Tags: android, android-activity, titlebar

When I swipe my app away in the recent apps view, the title bar of my app sticks at its initial position. I really have no idea whats wrong with my app, I couldn't even find anyone with the same problem.

The following screenshot shows the behavior:

[image: Android Screenshot]

This behavior can only be observed when my app is active at the moment of opening the recent apps view. If it's hidden and another app is active, the title bar is moving normally with the app.

Since I've really no idea what's the reason for this, I haven't posted any code snippets or something. The source code of my app is available on GitHub: https://github.com/rzueger/MFGT-Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at your code - this smells like an event problem.

I guess one of the following events is handled improperly in one of your activities:

- `onPause`
- `onClose`
- `onStop`

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further problems or findings.

Comment: Thx. There was a Activity#finish() call in my onPause handler.